# How to encode URL chunks

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-encoding

I'm developing a ASP.NET MVC application, and I'm managing file names in my URL paths. I need to encode url file names, to avoid errors on some paths (for example, when the character '+' is used, it fails under Mono/XSP).

But I need to encode only the file names, for example:

For example, given this input:

```
/dir1/this has spaces/file+name.txt
```

I need the following output:

```
/dir1/this%20has%20spaces/file%2bname.txt
```

Note that I don't want to encode the path separator. Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT**: I'm building my URL using the following:

```
   <%= Html.ActionLink(
            Html.Encode(revision.Name), 
            "Details", 
            "Items",
            Model.GetRouteParameters(revision.FullPath),
            null) %>
```

Where GetRouteParameters is the following:

```
public object GetRouteParameters(string path)
{
    return new 
    {
        repository = ItemProvider.GetBrowsingObject().Repository, 
        path = path, 
        browsing = ItemProvider.GetBrowsingObject().Name
    };
}
```

I would like to encode any "dangerous" character in the repository, the path or the browsing names.

Comment: How are you constructing those urls in the first place? This is where they should be encoded. Not subsequently. Once you get an invalid URL it's more difficult to *fix* it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` to encode the strings in a url safe way. You need to url encode the separate path components and then create the path.